# drupal 7 xpath feeds stand alone form, how do I set author of node?

Tags: feeds

I am using drupal 7, xpath feeds to import movie information from IMDB. Users are allowed to import movie information. To make this happen I am allowing users to use the stand alone form within feeds, however the author of the newly created feed is set to anonymous (or any other user that I set on the backend). How can I configure feeds in such a way that the user who submits the import is set as the author of the node that will be created?

I tried to change the settings
Basic Settings -> Attach to -> IMDB Content type

But using that will create two nodes .. one that retreived the IMDB information and the node that has been created..

Does anyone know how to do what I want?

Thanks in advance.